# Square root plot in matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, math.sqrt

How to make sqrt(x) function plot in matplotlib in python?

I tried writing `y = sqrt(x)` but it gave an TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. I have never had experience with matplotlib before, therefore I would be glad to get some advice.

Comment: How about looking at matplotlib [examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-simple-plot-py)?

Comment: Post your full code. A single line isn't enough to help you with anything.

Comment: @BlacKowBlab I looked at the examples - I had to use numpy.sqrt() instead of math.sqrt()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes a small example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
# print y = math.sqrt(x)

# calculate the points x, y
x = [0, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 25, 36, 49]
y = [math.sqrt(y) for y in x]
     
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
 
ax.set(xlabel='value', ylabel='sqrt', title='Square root of list values')
    
ax.grid()
fig.savefig("sqrt.png")

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
[![sqrt][1]][1]
```

Comment: I think it's too complex.

Comment: I tried to make it easier. You need the points x, y for the plt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `math.sqrt` to convert the x array to it's square root.
Instead use `np.sqrt`, this will return a numpy array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([4, 9, 16])
>>> y = np.sqrt(x)
>>> y
array([2., 3., 4.])
>>>
>>> math.sqrt(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
>>>
```

It's an error that happens when you try to pass an array to a function that only accepts 1 parameter. `np.int(y)` would yield the same error for example.

Comment: Yes, I did. I got the point, where I made a mistake. Thanks by the way.